# How can I delete a element from a vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, iterator

I'm developing a simple console based email application.

In my app, messages are stored in `std::vector`, and I want to add possibility to delete messages.

**How can I delete a element from a vector?**

Here's my code:

```
//MAIN MENU OPTION 1 SELECTED:
// print list of all messages to the console
void viewInbox() {
    vector<Message> inbox{
        Message("jayleno@hotmail.com", "Knife you tonight", "Hey Sam, what kind of suit do you wanna be buried in?!"),
        Message("paypalservices@hotmail.com", "Urgent from paypal.com", "Dear paypal user, someone has hacked your account. Give us your password now so we change it!"),
    };

    cout << "You have " << inbox.size() << " new messages.\n";
    cout << "Index      Subject" << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "Message " << i << ": " << inbox[i].getSubject() << '\n';

    cout << "Please enter number of message you would like to view\n";
    int read;
    cin  >> read;
    cout << "From: " << inbox[read].getAddress() << '\n';
    cout << "Subject: " << inbox[read].getSubject() << '\n';
    cout << inbox[read].getMessageText() << '\n';

    cout << "To erase this message press 1\n";
    //Code here for deleting a message...
}//end of viewInbox()
```

Comment: Use `\r` instead and just print spaces over it.

Comment: Hans Passant, not what I'm looking for. I need to also delete the message object from the vector if the user enters 1 in for the option.

Comment: @SamJava_The_Hut The title of your question is confusing, it suggests that you want to delete something from console, I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Is it really so difficult to search the web for an answer on how to delete elements from a `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

To erase a message from the vector use [vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) which takes an iterator.

The easiest way to get an iterator to a particular message is to use `inbox.begin() + message_number`.

I have refactored your code into smaller functions to make the code easier to work with:

```
  void viewMessage(vector<Message>& messages, size_t message_number) {
    vector<Message>::iterator message = messages.begin() + message_number;
    cout << "From: " << message->getAddress() << endl;
    cout << "Subject: " << message->getSubject() << endl;
    cout << message->getMessageText() << endl;

    cout << "To erase this message press 1\n";
    int erase;
    cin >> erase;
    // Maybe do some error checking on cin...
    if (erase == 1) {
      messages.erase(message);
    }
  }

  void viewMessages(vector<Message>& messages){
    auto inbox_size = messages.size();
    cout << "You have " << inbox_size << " new messages.\n";
    cout << "Index      Subject" << '\n';

    for (size_t i = 0u; i != inbox_size; ++i) {
      std::cout << "Message " << i << ": " << messages[i].getSubject() << '\n';
    }

    cout << "Please enter number of message you would like to view\n";
    size_t message_number;
    cin >> message_number;
    // Maybe do some error checking on cin...
    // And some bounds checking of message_number...
    viewMessage(messages, message_number);
  }

void viewInbox() {
  vector<Message> inbox{
    Message{ "jayleno@hotmail.com", "Knife you tonight", "Hey Sam, what kind of suit do you wanna be buried in?!" },
    Message{"paypalservices@hotmail.com", "Urgent from paypal.com", "Dear paypal user, someone has hacked your account. Give us your password now so we change it!"},
  };
  viewMessages(inbox);
  // Maybe call viewMessages again to see results of erase...
}
```

As I have commented, watch out for error checking on your input.